# Cannot convert value of type '[ArrayImages]' to expected argument type '[UIImage?]'

Tags: arrays, swift

I pass an array of images to the function ,

```
struct ArrayImages: Hashable {
    var asset: PHAsset
    var image: UIImage
}

@State var imagePost: [ArrayImages] = []
```

and then transfer to

```
uploadImages(images: **imagePost**, itemId: save.id) { ( imageLinkArray) in *// <- mistake here

save.imagePost = imageLinkArray
```

the function itself is such

```
let storage = Storage.storage()

func uploadImages(images: [UIImage?], itemId: String, completion: @escaping (_ imagePost: [String]) -> Void) {

    var uploadedImagesCount = 0
      var imageLinkArray: [String] = []
      var nameSuffix = 0

      for image in images {
          let fileName = "ItemImages/" + itemId + "/" + "\(nameSuffix)" + ".jpg"
        let imageData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)

          saveImageInFirebase(imageData: imageData!, fileName: fileName) { (imagePost) in

              if imagePost != nil {
                  imageLinkArray.append(imagePost!)
                 uploadedImagesCount += 1

                  if uploadedImagesCount == images.count {
                      completion(imageLinkArray)
                  }
              }
          }
          nameSuffix += 1
      }
```

}

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English site, so please post your question in English. Or perhaps you are looking for [Stack Overflow in Russian/Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract an array of `UIImage`s from your `imagePost`, that's easily done using `map`:

```
uploadImages(images: imagePost.map { $0.image }, itemId: save.id) { ( imageLinkArray) in 
    // ....
}
```